# Can \cite use bold font?

Tags: citing, bold

Is there an option which allows me to typeset bold hyperlinks? Here's a MWE explaining my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=Magenta}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}

@book{borgesESP,
  author = {Borges, J. L.},
  publisher = {Emecé},
  year = {1956},
  title = {Ficciones},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
``Mirrors and fatherhood are abominable'' \cite{borgesESP}

\bibliography{biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\hrulefill 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the "Bor56" to be in boldface. Is there a way to do this?

The naive way (modifying the `\cite` command) gives no result, or an error:

```
\newcommand{\citebf}[2][]{\cite[#1]{\bf #2}}
```

thinks the `\bf` as inside the reference label.

Comment: Perhaps consider reading [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can override the kernel `\@cite` macro to make it **bold**. But then you'd probably also like to make the label in the bibliography - `\@biblabel` - **bold**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=Magenta}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{borgesESP,
  author = {Borges, J. L.},
  publisher = {Emecé},
  year = {1956},
  title = {Ficciones},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{[\textbf{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textbf{#1}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
``Mirrors and fatherhood are abominable'' \cite{borgesESP}

\bibliography{biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer since it works in the MWE, but it doesn't work in the real file and I can't understand why!

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: Without posting something that reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say how to solve your issue. We can't read your mind...

Comment: Sure, I'm working on it; I was only saying "I'll be back".

Comment: Apparently, commenting the `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` row in the preamble makes everything work fine. Now, why does this happen? (you can use the former MWE, just de/commenting `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`)

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. With or without `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` I still receive the expected output. If you're still experiencing the same problem, please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem.