# Bolding numeric citations

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

Hi all I am cite sources in my report using the cite command:

```
\cite{test}
```

and I am using biblatex in Numeric mode:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric]{biblatex}
```

however I was hoping to make all of the the citations appear as bold, and was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction.

Edit* Similar to the following

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{RFC3550,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne and S. Casgner and R. Frederick and V. Jacobson},
    title = {RFC 3550, RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications},
    url = {https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550},
    year = {2003},
}

@report{RFC2326,
    author = {H. Schulzrinne and A. Rao and R. Lanphier},
    title = {RFC 2326, Real Time Streaming Protocol},
    url = {https://rools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326},
    year = {1998},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{RFC3550} and \cite{RFC2326}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@cite@ofmt}{\bfseries\hbox}
\makeatother`? Please provide an MWE!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53214, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23317, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250262, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251613, and maybe more. Please use the query in the upper right corner.

Comment: none of the above solutions work sadly

Comment: @LaRiFaRi It's gone now, never mind.

Comment: I suggest you specify the authors in your bibliography entries as `surname, given name`, so ` author = {Schulzrinne, H. and Rao, A. and Lanphier, R.}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will follow my answer to [making citations bold latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250262/35864), where we saw how to do this for `alphabetic` styles. For `numeric` the only thing that changes is the relevant field names, here they are `prefixnumber` and `labelnumber` (ordinarily, especially the latter one is important).

To bold labels use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

Un-bolding for the bibliography can be acheived via

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{#1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{#1}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}


\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{#1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} and \cite{geer} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want everything bold, you might like instead

```
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibboldbrackets}[1]{\mkbibbold{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibboldbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: absolute superstar, from a latex noob this is really appreciated thankyou

Comment: @TotalNewbie Always a pleasure, never a chore...