# Custom citation call-out format for individual bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I would like the numeric citation call-outs to some of the entries of my bibliography to be in bold.  Thus, citations in the main text should look something like:

> A nice summary may be found in [**7**].  See also [1, 3, **7**, 26, **38**] for further background information.

And likewise, in the bibliography, these entries should appear as:

> [1] M. Miller, *A not so short introduction to idiosyncracy* (2006).
>
> [2] C. Cartwheel, *Spinning: clock- and anticlockwise perspectives* (1998).
>
> ...
>
> [**7**] B. Bold, *The min-max principle in hereditary convolution* (2015).

Specifically, the entries of my .bib-file that I'd like to appear in bold are those of a certain author.  But this is not the crucial point—I'm perfectly willing to add some additional special markup to these entries, or to provide a separate list of the entry names.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I am currently using plain bibtex.  I would certainly be happy to switch to something more advanced, but rewriting the *whole* .bib-file in a different format is not an option.

Here's a minimal non-working example document …

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  A nice summary may be found in \cite{bb15}. 
  See also \cite{aaaa08,bb15,cc04,mm06} for 
  further background information.

  \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
  \bibliography{minimal.bib}
\end{document}
```

… together with a fairly minimal file `minimal.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{aaaa08,
 author = {Ant, A. and Aunt, A.},
 title = {The Rises and Falls of Fools and Balls},
 year = {2008},
}
@article{bb15,
 author = {Bold, B.},
 title = {The min-max principle in hereditary convolution},
 year = {2015},
}
@article{cc04,
 author = {Cartwheel, C.},
 title = {Spinning: clock- and anticlockwise perspectives},
 year = {2004},
}
@inproceedings{mm06,
 title={A not so short introduction to idiosyncracy},
 author={Miller, M.},
 year={2006},
}
```

Comment: Using `biblatex` you might have to add a `key` field to the entries you want the number of in bold. Is it too much?

Comment: No.  If that does the job it's definitely not too much.

Comment: OK. Could you post a minimal code (and .bib file) that we can play with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative with `biblatex`, in case you think it might be an alternative for you.

One possibility would be to create a category and add the entries you like to see in bold and then format the entries of the category:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{minimal.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bold}

\addtocategory{bold}{%
 cc04,
 }

\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{\ifcategory{bold}{\mkbibbrackets{\mkbibbold{#1}}}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifcategory{bold}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  A nice summary may be found in \cite{bb15}. 
  See also \cite{aaaa08,bb15,cc04,mm06} for 
  further background information.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

You could also do this using keywords, as suggested by Bernard. In this case, you should add `keywords={bold}` (or whatever other keyword you'd like, as long as it corresponds to the definitions below) to the entries of interest in your `.bib` file, and then use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{\ifkeyword{bold}{\mkbibbrackets{\mkbibbold{#1}}}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{bold}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
```

As far as I remember, I've seen here in this site a way to select the entries by the author's name, but I couldn't find.

Comment: In correcting my answer, I found moewe's https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263057/105447, so I made this CW.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I had to add `backend=bibtex` as a package option to `biblatex` for the minimal example to compile.  With this minor addition, the solution works perfectly (also for the real-world document).

Comment: Glad to hear it. Well, given the bibtex prepared bib file, in your case it makes perfect sense to use `backend=bibtex` (if you have non ascii content in there, you might be interested too in `bibtex8`). But, for the sake of others less thoughtful on the matter, I might well recall that `backend=bibtex` is now a legacy option from the point of view of `biblatex` and has limited support for its more advanced features.

Comment: Still, I edited the answer to include the backend which worked for you.

Comment: One tiny problem: it seems that the space reserved for the numbers in the bibliography is computed based on the non-bold entries.  If you look very closely at the example output above, you'll see that "C. Cartwheel" is moved a tiny fraction to the right because of the additional width of the [**3**].  This becomes more visible with 2- or 3-digit numbers in long bibliographies.  I managed to fix this manually by adding `\settowidth\labelnumberwidth{[\textbf{123}]}` just above `printbibliography`, but presumably that's not the best solution.

Comment: True. I admittedly don't know how to deal with that. If you feel that this must be better dealt with, I believe the best would be to ask another question (mentioning it is a follow up from this one).